# Как подобрать наилучшую функцию распределения и нарисовать графики плотностей подгоняемых распределений?

Tags: python, scipy, kde, distribution

Я начинаю изучать Python, пытаюсь для своих данных (98 значений от 0 до 1 (df1):
`0; 0;  0;  0,04;   0,07;   0,08;   0,08;   0,09;   0,09;   0,1;    0,11;   0,11;   0,11;   0,12;   0,14;   0,14;   0,14;   0,15;   0,17;   0,17;   0,17;   0,18;   0,18;   0,2;    0,22;   0,23;   0,24;   0,26;   0,27;   0,28;   0,28;   0,28;   0,29;   0,32;   0,33;   0,33;   0,35;   0,36;   0,38;   0,41;   0,42;   0,42;   0,43;   0,45;   0,45;   0,45;   0,46;   0,46;   0,49;   0,49;   0,52;   0,53;   0,54;   0,54;   0,56;   0,56;   0,58;   0,58;   0,6;    0,6;    0,62;   0,63;   0,64;   0,64;   0,64;   0,64;   0,65;   0,65;   0,66;   0,66;   0,67;   0,68;   0,68;   0,7;    0,7;    0,72;   0,74;   0,75;   0,76;   0,76;   0,77;   0,78;   0,79;   0,8;    0,81;   0,84;   0,84;   0,85;   0,87;   0,89;   0,89;   0,91;   0,93;   0,93;   0,96;   1;  1;  1)`
подобрать наилучшую функцию распределения и нарисовать графики плотностей подгоняемых распределений.
Использую пример [отсюда](https://coderoad.ru/6620471/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-Scipy-Python).
Но у меня не получается так же.
Вот мой код.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns

distrNameList = ['norm', 'gamma']
abscissias = np.linspace(0,1)
for distrName in distrNameList:
    distr = getattr(stats.distributions, distrName)
    param = distr.fit(df1)
    pdf = distr.pdf(abscissias, *param)
    plt.plot(pdf, label=distrName)
    plt.xlim(0,1)
sns.kdeplot(df1)
plt.legend(loc= 'upper right')
plt.show()
```

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что-нибудь. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за правки.

Comment: Я не знаю, что именно вам надо, но первый вопрос, который возник - а как у вас описан df1. В приведенном выше виде  - это точно не nump-массив.

Comment: В коде у меня df1 = [0, 0, 0, 0.04, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.12, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.15, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.18, 0.18, 0.2, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.29, 0.32, 0.33, 0.33, 0.35, 0.36, 0.38, 0.41, 0.42, 0.42, 0.43, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.46, 0.46, 0.49, 0.49, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.54, 0.56, 0.56, 0.58, 0.58, 0.6, 0.6, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.64, 0.65, 0.65, 0.66, 0.66, 0.67, 0.68, 0.68, 0.7, 0.7, 0.72, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8, 0.81, 0.84, 0.84, 0.85, 0.87, 0.89, 0.89, 0.91, 0.93, 0.93, 0.96, 1, 1, 1]. Спасибо.

Comment: Выполнил ваш код. Вполне пристойная KDE, особенно для приближения Гауссовой ф-цией. Что именно вас смущает?

Comment: Я хотел увидеть на одном графике несколько кривых. А у меня norm и gamma - прямые.

Comment: Норм -  точно не прямая.

Comment: Я хотел что-то похожее на это: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoCNk.png.

Comment: Ну, наберите пару тысяч объектов и получите что-то похожее. А чего вы ожидали при малых выборках и очень малом количестве интервалов?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Что именно??? Набрать объектов???  Так откуда я знаю, где и как генерируются ваши исходные данные.  Задачу сформулируйте более корректно, может что и подскажется.